# Shapes as border CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, border, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking to create a patterned border on the bottom of the div.

I've considered just using an image to achieve this, but then the div and the border does not respond properly when adjusting screen sizes.

I've considered using the mask property, but I'm not really sure how I can apply that to create this effect accurately.

EDIT:

I'm building this in WordPress with ACF. The code is seemingly irrelevant because I'm building it in a way that allow the end user to input values to style the block within WordPress.

I'd just like to know how you'd approach a border like this.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    <div id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="three-cards-center-text">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="cards-container">
    <?php
        if( have_rows('three_card_repeater') ):

            while( have_rows('three_card_repeater') ) : the_row();

                $title = get_sub_field('title');
                $copy = get_sub_field('copy');
                $image = get_sub_field('bottom_image'); ?>

                <div class="the-card">
                    <div class="title">
                        <?= $title ?> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="copy">
                        <?= $copy ?> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="<?= $image['url'] ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
  
           <?php endwhile;

        // No value.
        else : ?>
            <div></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#<?php echo esc_attr($id);?> {
    margin: <?php $three_card_margin = the_field('three_card_margin')?>;
    padding: <?php $three_card_padding = the_field('three_card_padding')?>;
}

#<?php echo esc_attr($id);?> .cards-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

#<?php echo esc_attr($id);?> .the-card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: <?php $card_bg_color = the_field('card_bg_color')?>;
    text-align: center;
    padding: <?php $card_padding = the_field('card_padding')?>;
    margin: <?php $card_margin = the_field('card_margin')?>;
}

#<?php echo esc_attr($id);?> .the-card .title{
    font-size: <?php $title_font_size = the_field('title_font_size')?>;
    color: <?php $title_font_color = the_field('title_font_color')?>;
    font-family: <?php $title_font_family = the_field('title_font_family')?>;
    font-weight: <?php $title_font_weight = the_field('title_font_weight')?>;
}

#<?php echo esc_attr($id);?> .the-card .copy{
    font-size: <?php $copy_font_size = the_field('copy_font_size')?>;
    color: <?php $copy_font_color = the_field('copy_font_color')?>;
    font-family: <?php $copy_font_family = the_field('copy_font_family')?>;
    font-weight: <?php $copy_font_weight = the_field('copy_font_weight')?>;

}
```

Comment: @HaimAbeles Sorry, that wasn't directed at you.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example to let you get the idea.

And there is many ways that this could be achieved.

basically, you add and SVG as a background image of a pseudo element.

```css
body { background: black; }
DIV.image {
   width: 480px;
   height: 200px;
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0qvs.png);
   position:relative;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.image::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon style="fill:red;" points="1,0 1,1 0,1 "/></svg>');
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: you can use an svg path generator to get the shape that you want.